# System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine doesn't work in ASP.NET 5 Web API

Tags: c#, debugging, logging, asp.net-core, dnx

### Environment

I am writing a Web API using ASP.NET 5 1.0.0-rc1-update1 and Visual Studio Code on Mac. I scaffolded the default Web API app using Yeoman `generator-aspnet`. I am using DNX Mono to run the app via the default `web` command.

### Missing output from `System.Diagnostics.Debug`

I want to log debug output to Terminal or to Visual Studio Code Output. I tried to do so using `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class, but the code above produces zero output.

```
System.Disagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This is your message");
```

What am I missing? Do I need to declare `DEBUG` symbol somewhere to see debug output?

### Missing from `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.DebugLogger`

I also tried [DebugLogger](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug) provided by `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug` package, but with no luck. Which I guess makes sense since it's a wrapper on top of `System.Diagnostics.Debug`. My `Startup.cs` configuration looked like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddDebug(LogLevel.Debug);

    // Configuring other middleware
}
```

I created`ILogger` in my controller as follows:

```
public ProductsController(ILoggerFactory logFactory)
{
    _logger = logFactory.CreateLogger(nameof(ProductsController));
}
```

And used `ILogger` as follows:

```
public IActionResult Ping()
{
    _logger.LogDebug("Debug message");
}
```

Comment: The debug logger should work as long as you write the message through the logging api. Is that what you're doing?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci, not exactly. I tried to use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` directly. `DebugLogger` is essentially a wrapper around it, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a TraceListener,

```
TextWriterTraceListener writer = new TextWriterTraceListener(System.Console.Out);
Debug.Listeners.Add(writer);
```

Also, set the `DEBUG` flag in the Visual Studio project properties

Answer (score 1):

While @Martin answers fixes the issue completely, I wanted to elaborate on logging `Debug` output in ASP.NET 5 a little.

### Using `System.Diagnostics.Debug`

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners` has only `System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener` by default which doesn't seem to write to console. If you add a console listener like @Martin suggested in his answer, both `System.Diagnostics.Debug` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug.DebugLogger` messages will start showing up in the console. For the latter to work, you also need to specify `DEBUG` symbol for your build.

It is worth noting that `System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners` property and `System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener` are not available in Core CLR 5.0.

### Using `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console.ConsoleLogger`

Initially, I tried [the recommended way](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html) to log messages to console in ASP.NET 5 is the new [`Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` API](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging). My `loggerFactory` was configured as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

    // Configuring other middleware
}
```

And I was trying to log debug messages using `_logger.LogDebug("Debug message");`. It didn't work and led me to try `System.Diagnostics.Debug` instead.

The gotcha was that ASP.NET 5 v1.0.0-rc1-update1 uses `ILoggerFactory.MinimumLevel` in addition to the log level provided when configuring a specific logger (e.g. `loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug)`). As described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/247#issuecomment-148451383)

> The minimum level indicates that any logs below the specified minimum
>   will not even be seen by loggers, no matter how hard they try.

This value [defaults to `Verbose`](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/LoggerFactory.cs#L34) which in 1.0.0-rc1-update1 is higher that `Debug`. Thus, unless you set `ILoggerFactory.MinimumLevel` to `LogLevel.Debug`, you won't see any debug output. See a similar issues reported [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/325).

Seems a little confusing, right? Good news is that ASP.NET 5 team has already fixed this "issue" and [removed](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/issues/298) `ILoggerFactory.MinimumLevel` property whatsoever in 1.0.0-rc2.

If you are still using 1.0.0-rc1-update1, then you need to configure logging as follows:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                      IHostingEnvironment env, 
                      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    // This line can be removed if you are using 1.0.0-rc2 or higher
    loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(LogLevel.Debug);

    // Configuring other middleware
}
```